# TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, backend

I'm trying to get a query from a MSSQL database using the mssql package in NodeJS. When I run my code, the error appears. Also the problem is that the error only appears in production, in development it works OK! :(

Here is my code

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const { config } = require("../database/config");
const sql = require("mssql");

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
 const {data1, data2} = req.body
 const query = `The Query is too long but it works!`

 switch (data1) {
 case 'subdata1':

// Making the connection to MMSQL
  const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(Config);
  const poolConnect = await pool1.connect() // The trace error indicates that the problem is in this line
                             //  ^^^ exactly here
       async function data1Path() {
        await poolConnect;  
         try {
           const request = await pool1.request();
           const result = await request.query(query);
           // Handling the query result
           return result.recordset[0].Direccion.replace(/\\/g, "/");
         } catch (error) {
           console.log("SQL Error: ", error);
         };
       };
       const getData1Query = await data1Path(); // Getting the path to find the file
 }
 case 'subdata2':
  // doing another things...

})
```

The next code is my database config file, I'm exporting it with module.exports:

```
const config = {
  server: DB_HOST,
  port: 1433,
  user: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASSWORD,
  database: "my_db_name",
  connectionTimeout: 180000,
  driver: "tedious",
  stream: "true",
  options: {
    appName: APP_NAME,
    encrypt: false,
    enableArithAbort: true,
  },
  pool: {
    max: 70,
    min: 0,
    idTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    log: true,
  },
};
```

I've been testing and testing and I can't find what is wrong. I hope you can help me I'm gonna be grateful a lot <3 :(

Comment: How do you set DB_HOST?

Comment: It is an IP so in my env variable I set it as: DB_HOST: 192.168.192.12 for instance

Comment: Is there any difference how you set it in development and production?

Comment: Not really, I'm using PM2 in order to keep running the Node process. I fact I'm not using pm2 with a bundled file it is just my index.js so, there is not any difference i think

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response <3

Comment: Is your IP address quoted when setting `DB_HOST`? The error message suggests to me that the config may be interpreted as `server: 192.168.192.12` (numeric) instead of `server: "192.168.192.12"` (string).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I've tried changing the env variable in DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD and at least the error desappears. I'm grateful. Now I have another error but I think that I can with it.  Again, THNKS A LOT <3

Comment: One thing to note is that my env variable does not work in production :/ I have to find another way :/

Comment: Output the whole config before you're using it (eg console.log). Compare develop vs production.